# AMP stack with Python

Tags: python, mysql, phpmyadmin

(This is a dumb question). Can i use phpmyadmin without the PHP? If so Is it practical to use Python with AMP stack? I just want the phpmyadmin as a GUI, I find it convenient web-based. Are there any lighterweight options with this kind of setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't use PHP MyAdmin without PHP! It is a web application written in PHP!

There's no reason you can't install PHPMyAdmin alongside a python application or perhaps a desktop MySQL GUI would be better for your needs, e.g. https://www.sequelpro.com/?